# Creating a free sendgrid account gives me a 'You are not authorized to access SendGrid' error

Tags: sendgrid, account, creation

I am not able to create a trial sendgrid account, I need to use sendgrid in a test credential area before operationalising this in Production, but not able to.

I created a free account successfully.

When I try to login, I get this error - You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support. You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support.

I do not get an actionable responses from the Support portal for this.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial or support. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)